# Does the Codex Amiatinus exist online anywhere in *text* format?

Tags: manuscript

Wondering if there is a complete [etext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-text) (i.e. not image or PDF) form of the Latin [Codex Amiatinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codex_Amiatinus) for free download online. Wikipedia links to [images](https://www.wdl.org/en/item/20150/), but I would like [text](https://github.com/7-rabbit/riff-text/blob/master/content/bible/lat/9.md).

Answer (score 3):

I have found a text copy on [The Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/codexamiatinusno00tsch/codexamiatinusno00tsch_djvu.txt), but the text appears to be an OCR rendering from scanned images—its quality is very uneven, to say the least.